# Angular ngIf not working inside ng-template

Tags: angular, nativescript

Hi I am using this nativescript plugin:

https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-accordion

I have the following code:

```
<StackLayout>
  <Accordion height="100%" [items]="items" allowMultiple="false" [selectedIndexes]="selectedIndexes">
    <ng-template let-i="index" let-item="item" acTemplateKey="title">
      <Label [text]="item.header"></Label>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template let-i="index" let-item="item" acTemplateKey="content">
      <ng-container *ngIf="item.type === 'product-wallet'">
        <Label text="WAHAHAHA"></Label>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- <app-product-transfer *ngIf="item.type === 'product-wallet'"></app-product-transfer> -->
    </ng-template>
  </Accordion>
</StackLayout>
```

This template throws an error saying:

> CONSOLE ERROR [native code]: ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an
>   object (evaluating 'newIndexes.length') CONSOLE ERROR [native code]:
>   ERROR CONTEXT { "view": { "def": { "nodeFlags": 639027201,
>   "rootNodeFlags": 1, "nodeMatchedQueries": 2, "flags": 0, "nodes": [ {
>   "nodeIndex": 0, "parent": null, "renderParent": null, "bindingIndex":
>   0, "outputIndex": 0, "checkIndex": 0, "flags": 1, "childFlags":
>   639027201, "directChildFlags": 33554433, "childMatchedQueries": 2,
>   "matchedQueries": {}, "matchedQueryIds": 0, "references": {},
>   "ngContentIndex": null, "childCount": 8, "bindings": [],
>   "bindingFlags": 0, "outputs": [], "element": { "ns": "", "name":
>   "StackLayout", "attrs": [], "template": null, "componentProvider":
>   null, "componentView": null, "componentRendererType": null,
>   "publicProvider<…> NativeScript caught signal 11. Native Stack: 1
>   0x10f2d81df sig_handler(int) 2   0x112f16b5d _sigtramp 3   0x1240cba00
>   4   0x113c7db65 -[UITableView
>   _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] 5   0x113cad363 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells] 6   0x113cb726b -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] 7   0x113c4b610 -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] 8   0x113c431f5 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] 9   0x113c5c571 -[UITableView _updateSections:withUpdateAction:rowAnimation:headerFooterOnly:usingPresentationValues:]
>   10  0x113c5c99c -[UITableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation:] 11 
>   0x14132d676 -[UITableViewAccessibility
>   reloadSections:withRowAnimation:] 12  0x10fbf451d ffi_call_unix64 13 
>   0x126482db0 JS Stack: 1   reloadSectionsWithRowAnimation@[native code]
>   2   reloadSection@file:///app/vendor.js:123034:49 3
>   handleTap@file:///app/vendor.js:123077:26 4
>   tableViewWillSelectRowAtIndexPath@file:///app/vendor.js:122990:22 5
>   UIApplicationMain@[native code] 6
>   start@file:///app/vendor.js:149361:26 7
>   run@file:///app/vendor.js:149389:10 8
>   bootstrapNativeScriptApp@file:///app/vendor.js:125890:26 9
>   bootstrapApp@file:///app/vendor.js:125791:38 10 
>   bootstrapModule@file:///app/vendor.js:125775:26 11 
>   @file:///app/bundle.js:8255:144 12 
>   ./main.ts@file:///app/bundle.js:8260:34 13 
>   **webpack_require**@file:///app/bundle.js:752:34 14  checkDeferredModules@file:///app/bundle.js:45:42 15 
>   @file:///app/bundle.js:828:38 16 
>   anonymous@file:///app/bundle.js:829:12 17  evaluate@[native code] 18 
>   moduleEvaluation@:1:11 19  promiseReactionJob@:1:11 20 
>   require@[native code] 21  anonymous@file:///app/starter.js:2:8 22 
>   evaluate@[native code] 23  moduleEvaluation@:1:11 24 
>   promiseReactionJob@:1:11

But when I tried to remove ngIf everything works. Why is that so?

Thanks!

Comment: `*ngIf="item?.type === 'product-wallet'"`

Comment: @Reactgular still doesnt work :(

Comment: I am pretty sure that item.type produces a value coz when I bind it to [text] property of Label it works!

Comment: The error didn't look like an expression error. So it was a shot in the dark.

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'newIndexes.length')  where is this coming from? newIndexes

Comment: try using  [ngIf] instead , [refer](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: If you still have issues, please share a Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduced.